# How to call count on an iterator and still use the iterator's items?

Tags: rust

`parts.count()` leads to ownership transfer, so `parts` can't be used any more.

```
fn split(slice: &[u8], splitter: &[u8]) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut parts = slice.split(|b| splitter.contains(b));

    let len = parts.count(); //ownership transfer

    if len >= 2 {
        Some(parts.nth(1).unwrap().to_vec())
    } else if len >= 1 {
        Some(parts.nth(0).unwrap().to_vec())
    } else {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    split(&[1u8, 2u8, 3u8], &[2u8]);
}
```

Comment: The thing is `slice.split` returns an `iterator`, which gets consumed and destroyed when you call `count()`. So... better `collect` the iterator into a `Vector`. As suggested by this answer by @Paolo

Comment: This is not a case of ownership-transfer but a case of lifetime-expiry.

Comment: thanks for your comment! @SarveshKumarSingh, I think the `count()` method is something like `count(parts: parts-type)`, when `parts` passes into `count`, it's owership is also be transfered.Am I thinking it right?

Comment: @std, you're absolutely correct. `count()` is defined like `fn count(self)`, which means that its target is moved into it, rendering the original variable invalid. This indeed is an ownership transfer.

Comment: I've updated your title to more clearly reflect that you aren't having issues with *splitting* a slice, but wanting to use the iterator *and* `count`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is also possible to avoid unnecessary allocations of `Vec` if you only need to use the first or the second part:

```
fn split<'a>(slice: &'a [u8], splitter: &[u8]) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
    let mut parts = slice.split(|b| splitter.contains(b)).fuse();

    let first = parts.next();
    let second = parts.next();

    second.or(first)
}
```

Then if you actually need a `Vec` you can map on the result:

```
split(&[1u8, 2u8, 3u8], &[2u8]).map(|s| s.to_vec())
```

Of course, if you want, you can move `to_vec()` conversion to the function:

```
second.or(first).map(|s| s.to_vec())
```

I'm calling [`fuse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fuse) on the iterator in order to guarantee that it will always return `None` after the first `None` is returned (which is not guaranteed by the general iterator protocol).

Comment: But this is strictly OK only because `split` never returns an empty iterator, isn't it?

Comment: No. If `split()` returns an empty iterator, the program will return `None`, just as your original one does. In this case both `first` and `second` will be `None`, and so `second.or(first)` will result to `None` as well.

Comment: Ah, but it seems it is not guaranteed by the [Iterator](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) protocol: "The Iterator protocol does not define behavior after None is returned. A concrete Iterator implementation may choose to behave however it wishes, either by returning None infinitely, or by doing something else." So the `Split` iterator does return `None` infinitely at the moment, but it could as well explode, couldn't it?

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant. You're absolutely correct, very nice catch. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The other answers are good suggestions to answer your problem, but I'd like to point out another general solution: create multiple iterators:

```
fn split(slice: &[u8], splitter: &[u8]) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    let mut parts = slice.split(|b| splitter.contains(b));
    let parts2 = slice.split(|b| splitter.contains(b));

    let len = parts2.count();

    if len >= 2 {
        Some(parts.nth(1).unwrap().to_vec())
    } else if len >= 1 {
        Some(parts.nth(0).unwrap().to_vec())
    } else {
        None
    }
}

fn main() {
    split(&[1u8, 2u8, 3u8], &[2u8]);
}
```

You can usually create multiple read-only iterators. Some iterators even implement [`Clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html), so you could just say `iter.clone().count()`. Unfortunately, [`Split`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Split.html) isn't one of them because it owns the passed-in closure.

Comment: Is this recommended solution? I'm asking because I would suspect that each split creates iterators on heap. And one iterator will be used just for counting and then can be forgotten..

Comment: @stej nothing in this code should create anything on the heap. However, you are right that one iterator is used just for counting and thrown away. For the case presented by the OP, I'd use [Vladimir Matveev's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28235022/155423) solution, but this solution may apply in similar but different situations.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Honestly, I sometimes have hard time how to learn what is on heap and what on stack. I didn't look more closely into doc, it was just a gut feeling.

Comment: @stej no worries! I also spoke a little hastily; I should have said "nothing about creating the **iterators** creates items on the heap". The `to_vec` calls will indeed create things on the heap. However, there's not really a way to avoid that if the OP wants to make `Vec`s ^_^.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is `collect` the results of the split in a new owned `Vec`, like this:

```
fn split(slice: &[u8], splitter: &[u8]) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    let parts: Vec<&[u8]> = slice.split(|b| splitter.contains(b)).collect();

    let len = parts.len();

    if len >= 2 {
        Some(parts.iter().nth(1).unwrap().to_vec())
    } else if len >= 1 {
        Some(parts.iter().nth(0).unwrap().to_vec())
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello again! 18 months later, I have more suggestions! ^_^ Instead of checking the length and then calling `unwrap`, you could instead [use slice::get](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get): [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=a6ab3f2dc6c9b7ad7a120d96cf7099b8&version=stable&backtrace=0). That leads nicely to [a simplification](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7baa74d673cbb590df100d9b998977af&version=stable&backtrace=0) that's very close to Vladimir Matveev's solution.